Sidecar pod StartupProbe Failed using Kubernetes Gateway API
I am doing a Kubernetes Gateway API travel in my own ,airgapped,non cloud based kubernetes platform
Following the Get Started Section https://istio.io/latest/zh/docs/setup/additional-setup/getting-started/,
All the deployment and gateway ,and istioctl install are same as the url before.
but, the sidecar pod reported a StartupProbe failed ,so the gateway API is not able to work.
Entering the pod log, it just tried to dial 169.254.169.254,
( HTTP request failed: Get "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2019-08-15": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers))
which seems to be a cloud platform based IP addr for metadata storing,the sidecar pod proxyv2 did the http request ,
it seems to be a istioctl issue, because a single proxyv2 pod runs successfully.
following the
set environment CLOUD_PLATFORM='none' did not work in a air gap and non cloud k8s platform
once install istioctl in demo profile, the exactly same error occurs in istio-ingress/egress gateway pod.
Version:
k8s: 1.30.2
istio 1.22.3
k8s gateway api version: v1
istioctl profile: minimal
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  gatewayClassName: istio
  listeners:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: HTTP
    allowedRoutes:
      namespaces:
        from: Same
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - name: bookinfo-gateway
  rules:
  - matches:
    - path:
        type: Exact
        value: /productpage
    - path:
        type: PathPrefix
        value: /static
    - path:
        type: Exact
        value: /login
    - path:
        type: Exact
        value: /logout
    - path:
        type: PathPrefix
        value: /api/v1/products
    backendRefs:
    - name: productpage
      port: 9080
and the kubectl describe pod show a startupProbe error:

 kubectl describe pod bookinfo-gateway-istio-6ccbf9b4f-qt8wm 
Name:             bookinfo-gateway-istio-6ccbf9b4f-qt8wm
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  bookinfo-gateway-istio
Node:             master/192.168.1.100
Start Time:       Sat, 27 Jul 2024 23:25:52 +0800
Labels:           gateway.networking.k8s.io/gateway-name=bookinfo-gateway
                  istio.io/gateway-name=bookinfo-gateway
                  pod-template-hash=6ccbf9b4f
                  service.istio.io/canonical-name=bookinfo-gateway-istio
                  service.istio.io/canonical-revision=latest
                  sidecar.istio.io/inject=false
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: ee2de49455458dca810dfda21a11819a3299556b4aeff4be0cab0a9bf70f71d9
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 172.27.205.163/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 172.27.205.163/32
                  istio.io/rev: default
                  prometheus.io/path: /stats/prometheus
                  prometheus.io/port: 15020
                  prometheus.io/scrape: true
Status:           Running
IP:               172.27.205.163
IPs:
  IP:           172.27.205.163
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/bookinfo-gateway-istio-6ccbf9b4f
Containers:
  istio-proxy:
    Container ID:  containerd://faafbba7c3c90e80643ebf60b519bed077d3f7eac89c86842ea6846f9eb87f83
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.22.3
    Image ID:      docker.io/istio/proxyv2@sha256:f43ddace4b6ab7265b1f6f8fe74a11fa86300add81be338333993e4e8205d07e
    Ports:         15021/TCP, 15090/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      proxy
      router
      --domain
      $(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
      --proxyLogLevel
      warning
      --proxyComponentLogLevel
      misc:error
      --log_output_level
      default:info
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sat, 27 Jul 2024 23:25:56 +0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   128Mi
    Readiness:  http-get http://:15021/healthz/ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=15s #success=1 #failure=4
    Startup:    http-get http://:15021/healthz/ready delay=1s timeout=1s period=1s #success=1 #failure=30
    Environment:
      PILOT_CERT_PROVIDER:           istiod
      CA_ADDR:                       istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
      POD_NAME:                      bookinfo-gateway-istio-6ccbf9b4f-qt8wm (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:                 default (v1:metadata.namespace)
      INSTANCE_IP:                    (v1:status.podIP)
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT:                (v1:spec.serviceAccountName)
      HOST_IP:                        (v1:status.hostIP)
      ISTIO_CPU_LIMIT:               2 (limits.cpu)
      PROXY_CONFIG:                  {}
                                     
      ISTIO_META_POD_PORTS:          []
      ISTIO_META_APP_CONTAINERS:     
      GOMEMLIMIT:                    1073741824 (limits.memory)
      GOMAXPROCS:                    2 (limits.cpu)
      ISTIO_META_CLUSTER_ID:         Kubernetes
      ISTIO_META_NODE_NAME:           (v1:spec.nodeName)
      ISTIO_META_INTERCEPTION_MODE:  REDIRECT
      ISTIO_META_WORKLOAD_NAME:      bookinfo-gateway-istio
      ISTIO_META_OWNER:              kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/bookinfo-gateway-istio
      ISTIO_META_MESH_ID:            cluster.local
      TRUST_DOMAIN:                  cluster.local
    Mounts:
      /etc/istio/pod from istio-podinfo (rw)
      /etc/istio/proxy from istio-envoy (rw)
      /var/lib/istio/data from istio-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/credential-uds from credential-socket (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/istio from istiod-ca-cert (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-njmgq (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/tokens from istio-token (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/workload-spiffe-credentials from workload-certs (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/workload-spiffe-uds from workload-socket (rw)
Conditions:
  Type                        Status
  PodReadyToStartContainers   True 
  Initialized                 True 
  Ready                       True 
  ContainersReady             True 
  PodScheduled                True 
Volumes:
  workload-socket:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  credential-socket:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  workload-certs:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  istio-envoy:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     Memory
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  istio-data:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  istio-podinfo:
    Type:  DownwardAPI (a volume populated by information about the pod)
    Items:
      metadata.labels -> labels
      metadata.annotations -> annotations
  istio-token:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  43200
  istiod-ca-cert:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      istio-ca-root-cert
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-njmgq:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  33m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/bookinfo-gateway-istio-6ccbf9b4f-qt8wm to master
  Normal   Pulled     33m                kubelet            Container image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.22.3" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    33m                kubelet            Created container istio-proxy
  Normal   Started    33m                kubelet            Started container istio-proxy
  Warning  Unhealthy  33m (x4 over 33m)  kubelet            Startup probe failed: Get "http://172.27.205.163:15021/healthz/ready": dial tcp 172.27.205.163:15021: connect: connection refused



2024-07-27T15:26:01.115128Z     info    Workload SDS socket not found. Starting Istio SDS Server
2024-07-27T15:26:01.115136Z     info    CA Endpoint istiod.istio-system.svc:15012, provider Citadel
2024-07-27T15:26:01.115138Z     info    Opening status port 15020
2024-07-27T15:26:01.115182Z     info    Using CA istiod.istio-system.svc:15012 cert with certs: var/run/secrets/istio/root-cert.pem
2024-07-27T15:26:01.121325Z     info    ads     All caches have been synced up in 5.038009041s, marking server ready
2024-07-27T15:26:01.121473Z     info    xdsproxy        Initializing with upstream address "istiod.istio-system.svc:15012" and cluster "Kubernetes"
2024-07-27T15:26:01.122145Z     info    Pilot SAN: [istiod.istio-system.svc]
2024-07-27T15:26:01.122514Z     info    Starting proxy agent
2024-07-27T15:26:01.122559Z     info    Envoy command: [-c etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev.json --drain-time-s 45 --drain-strategy immediate --local-address-ip-version v4 --file-flush-interval-msec 1000 --disable-hot-restart --allow-unknown-static-fields -l warning --component-log-level misc:error --concurrency 2]
2024-07-27T15:26:01.135657Z     info    sds     Starting SDS grpc server
2024-07-27T15:26:01.136019Z     info    sds     Starting SDS server for workload certificates, will listen on "./var/run/secrets/workload-spiffe-uds/socket"
2024-07-27T15:26:01.135907Z     info    starting Http service at 127.0.0.1:15004
2024-07-27T15:26:01.154136Z     warning envoy main external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:835   Usage of the deprecated runtime key overload.global_downstream_max_connections, consider switching to `envoy.resource_monitors.downstream_connections` instead.This runtime key will be removed in future.        thread=15
2024-07-27T15:26:01.154362Z     warning envoy main external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:928   There is no configured limit to the number of allowed active downstream connections. Configure a limit in `envoy.resource_monitors.downstream_connections` resource monitor.      thread=15
2024-07-27T15:26:01.159721Z     info    xdsproxy        connected to delta upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012   id=1
2024-07-27T15:26:01.170371Z     info    ads     ADS: new connection for node:bookinfo-gateway-istio-6ccbf9b4f-qt8wm.default-1
2024-07-27T15:26:01.170735Z     info    ads     ADS: new connection for node:bookinfo-gateway-istio-6ccbf9b4f-qt8wm.default-2
2024-07-27T15:26:01.182882Z     info    cache   generated new workload certificate      latency=61.367763ms ttl=23h59m59.817119728s
2024-07-27T15:26:01.182901Z     info    cache   Root cert has changed, start rotating root cert
2024-07-27T15:26:01.182910Z     info    ads     XDS: Incremental Pushing ConnectedEndpoints:2 Version:
2024-07-27T15:26:01.182930Z     info    cache   returned workload trust anchor from cache       ttl=23h59m59.817069728s
2024-07-27T15:26:01.182965Z     info    cache   returned workload certificate from cache        ttl=23h59m59.817035327s
2024-07-27T15:26:01.183062Z     info    cache   returned workload trust anchor from cache       ttl=23h59m59.816938526s
2024-07-27T15:26:01.183107Z     info    ads     SDS: PUSH request for node:bookinfo-gateway-istio-6ccbf9b4f-qt8wm.default resources:1 size:4.0kB resource:default
2024-07-27T15:26:01.183163Z     info    ads     SDS: PUSH request for node:bookinfo-gateway-istio-6ccbf9b4f-qt8wm.default resources:1 size:1.1kB resource:ROOTCA
2024-07-27T15:26:01.183200Z     info    cache   returned workload trust anchor from cache       ttl=23h59m59.816799725s
2024-07-27T15:26:01.305696Z     info    Readiness succeeded in 5.224696454s
2024-07-27T15:26:01.305827Z     info    Envoy proxy is ready
2024-07-27T15:26:06.114973Z     warn    HTTP request failed: Get "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2019-08-15": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2024-07-27T15:26:06.114986Z     warn    Could not unmarshal response: unexpected end of JSON input:
2024-07-27T15:56:14.159162Z     info    xdsproxy        connected to delta upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012   id=2

Version
istioctl version
client version: 1.22.3
control plane version: 1.22.3
data plane version: 1.22.3 (8 proxies)
kubectl version
Client Version: v1.30.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.30.2
